# Iterate over numbers in a column and get the first row number where the n amount of repetition starts

Tags: python, pandas, loops, while-loop

In my dataset I need to find when there are number of 0's repeated more than 280 times and get back the first row number of the start of the repetition in an array.I'm using python 3.11.

Sample data:

differences

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
.
.
.
5
5
.
.
0
0
0
0
```

or to create a sample dataset:

```
   ACD=[0,5]

   df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(ACD, 100, axis=0))
   df3=df2.sample(frac=1,axis=1).sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

So far my code:

```
c=[]
for values,row in df.loc[:, ['differences']].iterrows():
        i=0
        while row['differences']  == 0:
            count = sum(1 for i in row)
            i +=1
            if count > 280:
                continue
            c.append(np.where(row['differences']))
        else:
            values+=1
```

Expected output:

```
row_number_rep= [5,90,120] #showing the specific row numbers where the repetition stars.
```

With this code I get the error

> <stdin>:8: DeprecationWarning: Calling nonzero on 0d arrays is deprecated, as it behaves surprisingly. Use `atleast_1d(arr).nonzero()` if the old behavior was intended.

I need help to improve this code. I think the problem is that I do not have first 280 items as 0's and I need to keep iterating over the whole column to find all the row number of beginning of 0's repeated 280 times.

Comment: Can you craft a small example with a threshold of 5 instead of 280 and provide the matching expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### pandas approach

Assuming this example and a threshold of `4` (instead of `280`):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'differences': [0,0,0,0,0,1,2,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,5]})

    differences
0             0  # 0: first stretch of >4
1             0
2             0
3             0
4             0
5             1
6             2
7             0
8             3
9             0  # 9: second stretch of >4
10            0
11            0
12            0
13            0
14            0
15            4
16            0
17            5
```

You could perform a [`groupby.size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.size.html) to filter the [`groupby.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.first.html):

```
thresh = 4

m = df['differences'].eq(0)
group = (~m).cumsum().to_numpy()

g = df.reset_index()[m].groupby(group[m])
g.size()

out = g['index'].first()[g.size()>thresh].to_numpy()
```

Output: `array([ 0, 9])`

###### loop approach

```
lst = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
thresh = 4

start = -1
zeros = False
count = 0
out = []
for i, v in enumerate(lst+[-1]):
    if v==0:
        if not zeros:
            count = 0
            start = i
            zeros = True
        count += 1
        continue
    if count > thresh:
        if zeros:
            out.append(start)
    zeros = False

out
# [0, 9, 18]
```

###### [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) approach:

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
thesh  = 4

out = [x[0][0] for k,g in groupby(enumerate(lst), key=lambda x: x[1]==0)
       if k and len(x:=list(g))>thresh]
# [0, 9, 18]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, since it is simple and works perfectly. I am curious to see though how would it work with a while loop. Thank you!

Comment: @IrmakOzarslan sure, I added a loop, but you shouldn't use it with pandas

Comment: Thank you so much! I just have one question: in the 3rd approach can you explain the  " x[0][0]"?

Comment: @Irmak sure, since we `groupby` on `enumerate`, the items are pairs of `(index, value)`. The first `[0]` gets the first pair, the second `[0]` gets the index. You can rewrite this one as a classical loop to see the intermediates ;)